# Solving the inequalities with constraints on function parameters.

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

Is there any way to show that the following inequality holds for the given functions with constraints?

Let $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}+(1-a)x-(1-a)y-1)$,

$f_2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}-(1-a)x+(1-a)y-1)$, and

$f_3(x) = \frac{(1-a)(y+1)x}{(1-a)y+1}$, such that

$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{f_1(x)}\right)^{f'_1(x)}\left(1+\frac{1}{f_2(x)}\right)^{f'_2(x)}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{f_3(x)}\right)^{f'_3(x)}} \geq 1$, for $0.5 \leq a \leq 1$, $x >0,y \geq 0$. It can be easily checked that it saturates the inequality for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$.

Here is the full expression:

$\frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}+(1-a)x-(1-a)y-1\right)}\right)^{\frac{(1 - a) (1 + (1+a) y + (1-a)x)}{2\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}}+\frac{(1-a)}{2}}\left(1+\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}-(1-a)x+(1-a)y-1\right)}\right)^{\frac{(1 - a) (1 +(1+a) y + (1-a)x)}{2\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}}-\frac{(1-a)}{2}}}{\left(1+\frac{(1-a)y+1}{(1-a)(y+1)x}\right)^{\frac{(1-a)(y+1)}{(1-a)y+1}}} \geq 1$..

I have noticed the following points:
Each $f_i(x) > 0 $ for the given constraints! Hence all individual terms inside the big brackets are greater than 1. Moreover, the term written in the power of each bracket is always $\geq 0$.

Numerically, I've checked this for different range of $x,y$ and $a$. It always holds.. I'm not sure how I can prove this analytically! Actual expression was in terms of $\log$ functions and it was required to show that the $\log$ function is always positive $\rightarrow$ the above mentioned function is always $\geq 1$.

I am sorry for such a complex form of the expression. 
Thanks!

Comment: Additional information: according to numerical simulations, it is always greater than 1 but it's very close to 1.. That's the reason why I am unable to show it analytically. If I take any approximation, it immediately brings this expression below 1....

Comment: `Actual expression was in terms of log functions and ...` Wondering what was *before* that actual expression. The way it ended up in the posted question is not too pretty, but maybe there is another way to transcribe the very original problem.

Comment: thanks @dxiv.. I will upload my original question!...

Comment: @dxiv.. I have posted the original question.. Please have a look...

Comment: I meant the original problem *before* it "reduced" to this form. There is obviously some relationship between $f_1,f_2,f_3\,$, for example $f_1,f_2$ are the roots of a quadratic, and $f_1=f_3$ when $y=0\,$. It's unlikely that those are pure coincidences, so I was wondering whether there is some maybe deeper relationship which could help with framing the problem from a different angle. As it is now, nothing blatantly obvious jumped at me.

Comment: Hi @dxiv.. May be I wasn't clear.. I actually have posted the original question separately. here it is [concavity of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361327/concavity-of-a-function)..