# Concavity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let g be a concave function such that

$g[x] = (1+x) \log(1+x) - x\log(x)$,

where $x>0$. Show that the following function is concave for given constraints on the parameters:

$f[x] = g[\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}+(1-a)x-(1-a)y-1)]+g[\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{(1+(1+a) x+(1-a) y)^2-4 a x (1+x)}-(1-a)x+(1-a)y-1)] - g[(1- \frac{a}{(1-a)y+1})x],$

where $x>0, y\geq 0 $ and $0.5 \leq a \leq 1$.

---

My observations:

I actually need to show that this function attains maxima at $x\rightarrow \infty$. For that it can be easily checked that first derivative goes to zero at $x\rightarrow \infty$. Moreover the function $\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. If it can be shown that the function is concave then it solves the problem. I think it should also be okay if one can show that first derivative is always positive $\forall x>0$, except $x\rightarrow \infty$.

I have checked the function numerically and it's always concave irrespective of any value of parameters $a$ and $y$.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It's easy to check that the first derivative of any g function as defined above can be written as:

$g'[f[x]] = f'[x]\log(1+\frac{1}{f[x]})$.

Moreover, second derivative can be given as:

$g''[f[x]] = f''[x]\log(1+\frac{1}{f[x]}) - \frac{(f'[x])^2}{f[x](f[x]+1)}$.

Comment: Does anyone have any intuitive way to solve this complicated calculation?